# ConstraintLayout: how to divide screen in two equal parts of screen height programmatically

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

How to divide the screen in two equal part wrt height with constraint layout programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to set the height to zero then set the percent accordingly. For e.g.,

```
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) viewTop.getLayoutParams();
    lp.height = 0;
    lp.matchConstraintPercentHeight = (float) 0.5;
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)viewBottom.getLayoutParams();
    lp2.height = 0;
    lp2.matchConstraintPercentHeight = (float) 0.5;
    viewTop.setLayoutParams(lp);
    viewBottom.setLayoutParams(lp2);
```